# How does one get a list of Documents via the Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api

I need to be able to retrieve a list of `Document`s using the Metadata API.

According to the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_document.htm), "To retrieve the list of **documents** for populating package.xml with explicit names, call listMetadata() and pass in DocumentFolder as the type." Contrary to this sentence, this call returns a list of `DocumentFolder`s, not `Document`s, which makes sense since we asked for a list of `DocumentFolder`s.

I have the exact use case described by the docs, which is I need to "retrieve the list of documents for populating package.xml with explicit names." So, how do I get actual Document names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be an error in this part of the documentation, what you actually need to do is set the **Folder** in the [ListMetadataQuery](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listmetadataquery.htm) parameter, leaving the **Type** set to Document.

> The folder associated with the component. This field is required for components that use folders, such as Dashboard, Document, EmailTemplate, or Report.

```
ListMetadataQuery query = new ListMetadataQuery();
query.setType("Document");
query.setFolder("MyFolder");
```